# How do I merge two dataframes and match the two different participant IDs in R Studio?

Tags: r, merge

I have two sets of data for the participants. Time 1 and time 2. How do I match them when I merge them? I tried using the matching function. I have the 'tidyverse' package if that helps at all. Below is where I am stuck at.

```
DF3 <- merge(DF1, DF2, all = TRUE, by = intersect("id1"(1), "id2"(t2-id-0)))
```

The desired output is the following

```
> id1 ..... id2
>  0         t2-id-0
>  1         t2-id-1      
>  2         t2-id-2
```

Comment: What is the outcome that you're looking for? What happened when you tried the matching function?

Comment: There was an error showing that it could not find my function "id2", which is clearly a variable in that data set. It also said that" 'id1()' is deprecated". @ThrawnCA

Comment: I just added the output to the question @ThrawnCA